# Deploy a simple python bot on Openshift

Tags: python, deployment, openshift

This is a very simple pure python app (not Django or Flask).

**What is the step-by-step and correct way of deploying this app on *Openshift* ?**, so that it runs forever.

**Code:**

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time
url = "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html"
page = rq.get(url).content
soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
response = soup.find('img')
if response == None:
    imglink = soup.find('iframe')['src']
else:
    imglink = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + response['src']
def main():
    while True:
        sess = rq.Session()
        cid='@*********'
        turl = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot****************/'
        if response == None:
            imglink = soup.find('iframe')['src']
            params = {'chat_id':cid,'text':imglink}
            sess.post(turl + 'sendMessage', data=params)
        else:
            imglink = 'https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/' + response['src']
            title = soup.find('b').get_text()
            params = {'chat_id':cid,'photo':imglink,'caption':title}
            sess.post(turl + 'sendPhoto', data=params)
        time.sleep(30)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Most of the steps provided by the open shift for deploying flask applications should be valid for this script too.

Comment: I dont anything about deplyment, I tried to search tutorials but they all use Django or Flask. They use some extra steps to deploy.

Comment: Try those steps, just ignore the flask part. Because those are also single page scripts with flask objects in them.

Comment: It uses git repo, So I dont know to create it.

Comment: You need to use git, otherwise, there is no use of having CI/CD deployment.

Comment: May I know how to use or create ***git***

Comment: There are a lot of online courses available for the same. Google it. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Do you have access to the frontend? The frontend makes it really easy to do this in Openshift.

Answer (score 2):

### use following on commands on terminal

1. oc login -u admin

### After login in openshift cluster create new project

2. oc new-project python

### Create an application in project python

3. oc new-app python~**https:// repository url where your application is
   located** --name myapp

### get the status of created pod

4. oc status

### expose the service of pod

5. oc expose svc/myapp